# Can't get value for PSTitleValueSpecifier

Tags: objective-c, ios, settings

I am trying to get/set values from Settings.bundle->Root.plist in my code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *val = [defaults objectForKey:@"NUMBER"];
```

But val is nil. Is it all correct in my code?

Here is my Root.plist

```
       <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSTitleValueSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>MyTitle</string>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>NUMBER</string>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <string>SavedNumbers</string>
        <key>Values</key>
        <array>
            <string>SavedNumbers</string>
        </array>
        <key>Titles</key>
        <array>
            <string>5</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Comment: [defaults objectForKey:@"NUMBER"]; where "NUMBER" is a value not the Key

Answer (score 0):

in the  the  tag specifiees the key and the respective below tag is the value(it can any , etc).

so when you call objectForKey: you need to pass the  value, so that it will return the object for that key.

But in your case you are passing value "NUMBER" instead of key.

a dictionary consists of key value pairs.

if you need all keys for the object you need to use

```
- (NSArray *)allKeysForObject:(id)anObject
```

Comment: I need get/set value from:
        <array>
            <string>5</string>
        </array>

Comment: From the documentation about  <key>Key</key>
        <string>NUMBER</string>

Key (required) String

The preference key identifying the value. This is the string you use this to retrieve the preference value from the defaults database.
This key is required.